# Apache Zeppelin 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT not working with external Spark

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use Zeppelin (0.7-0 snapshot compiled with  mvn clean package -Pcassandra-spark-1.6 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests)
with an external, standalone Spark of version 1.6.1

I have tried to set this up by entering export MASTER=spark://mysparkurl:7077 in /zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh
and under the %spark interpeter settings, through the Zeppelin GUI I have also tried to set the master-parameter to spark://mysparkurl:7077.

So far, attempts to connect to Spark have been unsuccessful. Here is a piece of code I have used for testing Zeppelin with external spark and the error I get with it:

```
%spark 
val data = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
val distData2 = distData.map(i => (i,1))
distData2.first

data: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
```

Zeppelin is running in a docker container, and Spark is running on host.

Am I missing something here? Is there something else that needs to be configured in order for Zeppelin to work with an external, standalone Spark?

Comment: Did you compile the external spark as well? by default spark 1.6 using scala-2.10

Comment: Yes, I compiled the external spark. In spark root directory I executed ./dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh and then sbt -Dscala-2.11 clean assembly. At startup, the external Spark says                                                         Using Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_80)

Comment: There are be some clue in zeppelin logs directory, specially the zeppelin-interpreter-spark-xx.log file

Comment: The log files didn't contain anything useful in this case. It seems to be a version combination/incompatibility issue. We were able to make these combinations work by simply setting the spark master in the GUI and in zeppelin-env.sh: spark 1.6.1 & scala 2.10, spark 2.0 & scala 2.11. The one combination we would have needed at this stage, spark 1.6.1 & scala 2.11 did not work (as of 16/08/2016).

Comment: I believe you have to compile 0.7 snapshot with -Dscala-2.10 . I have the exact same setup you describe and it worked.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

As [Cedric H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420892/cedric-h) mentions, at that time you have to compile Apache Zeppelin with `-Dscala-2.10`.

Few bugs have been fixed since Sept and Scala 2.11 support should be working now well, if not - please file an issue in [official project JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN).